# PDO PHP connection timeout but tsql commandline connect works

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, connection-timeout

Suddenly I have started experiencing a connection timeout 100% of the time from my local environment when using PDO in PHP for SQL Server.

This started happening without any changes to pdo config or server config. The error I am getting is :

```
PHP Fatal error:  500 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out #0 [internal function]: PDO->__construct
```

- connection works fine from different server with same config
- connection works fine when connecting through telnet on port 1433, so the port is open:

> [root@webserver]# telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 1433
>
> Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
>
> Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.

- connection works fine with tsql from command line and I can successfully run queries:

> [root@webserver]# TDSVER=7.1 tsql -H xx.xx.xx.xx -p 1433 -U [user] -P [pass]
>
> locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
>
> locale charset is "UTF-8"
>
> using default charset "UTF-8"
>
> 1>

- my configuration looks like this, and it has not changed since it last worked (or ever for that matter):

> $connection = new \Db\Adapter\Pdo\MsSql(array(
>
> ```
>            'host' => $config->mssql->host,
>            'username' => $config->mssql->username,
>            'password' => $config->mssql->password,
>            'dbname' => $config->mssql->dbname,
>            'pdoType'  => $config->mssql->pdoType,
>            'dialectClass' => $config->mssql->dialectClass,
>            'port' => 1433
>        ));
> ```